# Different logic produced by clang and gcc for same code. Which is correct?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

I have found a discrepancy between the logic produced by gcc-8 and clang-6.

This happened in a real code base, when having developed using clang, I deployed using gcc.

Please kindly advise which compiler is in error so that I can file a bug appropriately.

#### Synopsis

`A` is implicitly convertible to `B`
`A` is constructible from both an `A` (copy/move) and `std::initializer_list<B>`.

When initialising an `A` from an `A&&`:

- clang selects the move-constructor
- gcc selects the `initializer_list` constructor.

live demonstration: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc50bd8f040d6476

#### MCVE

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct thing;

struct thing_ref
{
    thing_ref(thing&& other) : ref_(other) {}
    thing_ref(thing& other) : ref_(other) {}

    thing& ref_;
};

struct thing
{
    thing() {}

    thing(std::initializer_list<thing_ref> things)
    {
        std::cout << "initializer_list path\n";
    }

    thing(thing&& other)
    {
        std::cout << "move path\n";
    }

    thing(thing const& other)
    {
        std::cout << "copy path\n";
    }
};

struct foo
{
    foo(thing t) : mything { std::move(t) } {}
    thing mything;
};

int main()
{
    thing t;

    auto f = foo { std::move(t) };
}
```

#### Compiler settings:

Nothing special, as per the coliru link: `-std=c++17 -O2`

Comment: With what standard settings do you compile?

Comment: I don't think either are wrong as std::move is a suggestion to the compiler. std::move is actually an rvalue cast. rvalue is used in initializer list so that is correct. At the same time it could be move so that is correct too. I would expect it to be a move though. Also if you change from uniform initialization in foo, as in `mything(std::move(t))` then both use move constructor.

Comment: @bartop as per the coliru link, `-std=c++17 -O2` but the same happens with `-O0`. I'll update the question for clarity.

Comment: @Ashkan editing the code to remove the uniform initialisation was by bugfix (after some time tracking down the cause of the error...)

Comment: @RichardHodges My point was that it is reasonable to see an rvalue inside uniform initialization as a initializer_list. It is not the smartest maybe but it is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard draft (`T` is `thing`) [[dcl.init.list]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.list#3):

> List-initialization is initialization of an object or reference from a braced-init-list. ...
>
> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>
> - If the braced-init-list contains a designated-initializer-list [does not apply]
> - If T is an aggregate class and *[does not apply]*
> - Otherwise, if T is a character array *[does not apply]*
> - Otherwise, if T is an aggregate *[does not apply]*
> - Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements *[does not apply]*
> - Otherwise, if T is a specialization of `std::initializer_­list<E>` *[does not apply]*
> - Otherwise, if T is a class type, constructors are considered.
>     The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen through overload resolution ***[applies]***
> - ...

[[over.match.list]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.list):

> When objects of non-aggregate class type T are list-initialized such that [dcl.init.list] specifies that overload resolution is performed according to the rules in this subclause, overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
>
> - **Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors** ([dcl.init.list]) of the class T and the argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument. ***[applies]***
> - **If no viable initializer-list constructor is found**, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class T and the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list.
>
> If the initializer list has no elements and T has a default constructor, the first phase is omitted. [does not apply]

Back to [dcl.init.list] to find out what an [*initializer-list constructor*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#list-2) is:

> A constructor is an initializer-list constructor if its first parameter is of type `std::initializer_­list<E>` or reference to possibly cv-qualified `std::initializer_­list<E>` for some type E, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments ([dcl.fct.default]).

There is also a handy note, that reasserts the conclusion:

> Note: Initializer-list constructors are favored over other constructors in list-initialization

My conclusion:

The initializer-list constructor candidate should be considered first, and used if it is valid. As `thing` implicitly converts to `thing_ref`, it should be valid. It appears to me that GCC is conforming.

If you want to initialize an object of type that has an initializer-list constructor, but don't want to use that constructor, then don't use list initialization i.e. don't use a brace-init-list.

Comment: What about [DR 2137](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2137)?

Comment: @rustyx hmm, if I read that correct, Clangs behaviour was correct prior to that change.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive (if rather depressing) answer. It seems to me that logically a copy/move constructor intuitively ought to be preferred to that of an initializer_list of another type.